# Django validate fileds on form and return on template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I cant understand how to return error in template.

I making check on valid in my from
it look like junior mistake but im try different varinats but I could not solve this problem

FORMS.py

```
class UserForm(forms.Form):
    first_name= forms.CharField(max_length=20, label='Name')
    last_name= forms.CharField(max_length=20, label='Last_name')
    password= forms.CharField(label='Password')
    repassword= forms.CharField(label='Confirm password')
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        self.password = cleaned_data('password')
        self.repassword = cleaned_data('repassword')
        if self.password != self.repassword:
            raise ValidationError('Password dont match')
```

This is my views code
i`m trying validate in def index and have same error

VIEWS.py

```
def index(request):
    form = UserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            firstname= form.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
            lastname= form.cleaned_data.get("last_name")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            re_password = form.cleaned_data.get('repassword')
     form = UserForm()
            context = {'form': form,
                    }
            return render(request, 'create_users/index.html', context)
    return render(request, 'create_users/index.html', {'form': form}
```

As result i see this when update my template

this is is a part of template

**template**

```
<form action="{% url 'create_users:add_user' %}" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
    <div class="mb-3">
      {{ field }}
    </div>
    {% for error in field.errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{error}}</div>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
      <button class="btn btn-primary d-block w-100" type="submit" style="--bs-primary: #7286a4;--bs-primary-rgb: 114,134,164;background: rgb(100,105,113);">Create</button>      
</form>
```

and finaly error message
**traceback**

```
        Environment:
    Request Method: POST
    
    Django Version: 4.1.5
    Python Version: 3.11.0
    Installed Applications:
    ['django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'create_users.apps.CreateUsersConfig']
    Installed Middleware:
    ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Dev\routerOS\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "C:\Dev\routerOS\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "C:\Dev\routerOS\admin_console\create_users\views.py", line 13, in index
        if form.is_valid():
      File "C:\Dev\routerOS\env\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 205, in is_valid
        return self.is_bound and not self.errors
      File "C:\Dev\routerOS\env\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 200, in errors
        self.full_clean()
      File "C:\Dev\routerOS\env\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 438, in full_clean
        self._clean_form()
      File "C:\Dev\routerOS\env\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 459, in _clean_form
        cleaned_data = self.clean()
      File "C:\Dev\routerOS\admin_console\create_users\forms.py", line 26, in clean
        self.password = cleaned_data('password')
    
    Exception Type: TypeError at /create_users/
    Exception Value: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Comment: Can you put the whole traceback of the error and add the relevant template code.

Comment: ok,  i make it at answer

Comment: Why you didn't edit the question?

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in your `clean` method.

```py
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        # self.password = cleaned_data('password')
        self.password = cleaned_data.get('password')
        # self.repassword = cleaned_data('repassword')
        self.repassword = cleaned_data.get('repassword')
        if self.password != self.repassword:
            raise ValidationError('Password dont match')
```

Also, keep in mind that there are two ways to validate fields in the form:

1. `clean` method - should be used when there are two or more interdependent fields that require validation
2. `clean_<field_name>` method - clean method for a single field

This is important because the errors are stored differently for these two methods. The `clean_<field_name>` method stores the errors in the `form.errors` dict which you are correctly rendering in your HTML. However, `clean` method stores the errors in `form.non_field_errors`. To render these I suggest adding this line above your form code:

```html
<form action="{% url 'create_users:add_user' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    
    {# Renders errors reported in clean method #}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}

    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="mb-3">
            {{ field }}
        </div>
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{error}}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    ...     
</form>
```

#### One last thing

I found some issues in your view code. I will add below a commented version of your code:

```py
def index(request):
    form = UserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            firstname= form.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
            lastname= form.cleaned_data.get("last_name")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            re_password = form.cleaned_data.get('repassword')

            # DON'T override the form here. If the form is invalid
            # you want to re-render that exact form instance because
            # it will contain the errors
            # form = UserForm()
            context = {'form': form}

            # If the form is valid, you want to redirect to the success page
            # See this antipattern: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/rendering-content-after-a-successful-post-request.html
            return render(request, 'create_users/index.html', context)
    return render(request, 'create_users/index.html', {'form': form}
```

Comment: thaks, but why error dont display on template?

Comment: It's a TypeError, not validation error. This isn't caught by the form code.

Comment: ok,   error in sintax is done.  How to check validation error  by the form code

Comment: I edited the answer to give you more details